# React и Сканер штрих кодов

Tags: javascript, reactjs, штрихкод

есть React приложение в котором можно осуществить поиск в списке товаров по имени, id, штрих коду. Весь этот поиск осуществляется с помощью одного input. т.е. вводишь любые данные, а скрипт сам ищет по всем возможным полям и выдает результат.

Есть сканер штрих кода (эмуляция клавиш) ставлю фокус на input, сканирую штрих код и все работает. Но есть нюанс, нужно сделать так, чтобы при повторном сканировании из input стирались старые данные и вводились сканером новые.

Проблемы:

- сканер набирает быстро, а человек медленно - реализовать идею с помощью таймеров не получилось, так как нужна возможность ввода штрих кода, название товара человеком
- в input можно вводить не только штрих код, но и названия товаров - идея удалять данные после определенной длинны тоже не подошло

Какие советы?

Comment: А есть ли доступ к коду сканера? Можно попробовать вариант, в котором обязать сканер перед вводом кода штрихкода вводить ключевую последовательность из символов (мол "!£$!"), в input'e же отслеживать появление этой последовательности и очищаться. Если ввод сканером происходит "мгновенно", то для глаза это будет незаметно.

Comment: @Saionaro Доступа к коду нет. Да и планируется использование в больших количествах во многих точках, так что менять для каждого сканера код тоже не вариант

Comment: Для сканера заведите отдельный инпут, можно скрытый. Фокус будет всегда на скрытом инпуте, за исключением когда пользователь вручную поставит фоку на инпут для ввода, после снятия фокуса для ввода фокус снова будет на скрытом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение не универсальное, подходит только для штрих кодов стандарта `EAN-13`. Для других стандартов нужно доработать.

```
import React from 'react';
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

class Search extends React.Component {
    state = {
        value: '',
        lastValue: ''
    }
    delayedCall = debounce((value) => {
        if(value.length - this.state.lastValue.length === 13 && !/[^[0-9]/.test(value.slice(-13))) {
            this.setState({value: value.slice(-13), lastValue: value.slice(-13)});
            console.log('code -', value.slice(-13));
        } else {
            this.setState({lastValue: value});
            console.log('search - ', value);
        }
    }, 200);
    handleChange = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({value: value});
        this.delayedCall(value);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} 
            />
        );
    }
}
export default FilterForm;
```